# Pygame: get_at consistently returning 'None'

Tags: python, oop, pygame, game-development

I'm trying to detect whether a player in Pygame (a red rectangle) has collided with a red box by detecting the colour of the pixel underneath the player's rectangle; however, when I use the get_at() method in Pygame, it consistently returns 'None' even though the player is on a colour.

Here's the function detecting the colour:

```
def get_color(x, y):
   screen.get_at((x, y))
```

And here's where I call the function (p1.x is the x coordinate of player 1, and p1.y is the y coordinate of player 1, also, my background is black because I don't fill the background with any colour throughout the program):

```
if get_color(p1.x, p1.y) != black:
    print(get_color(p1.x, p1.y))
```

The last print statement above keeps on returning "None" even when the player is clearly on top of a red box.

Comment: you have to use `return` in last line `return screen.get_at((x, y))` - if you don't do this then Python will use `return None` as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `return` in your function to return value from `get_at()`

```
def get_color(x, y):
   return screen.get_at((x, y))
```

If you don't use `return` then Python uses `return None` as default so it works like

```
def get_color(x, y):
   screen.get_at((x, y))
   return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_color` function is not returning a value. Written correctly, your `get_color` function should be:

```
def get_color(x, y):
    return screen.get_at((x, y))
```

Just a side note, you don't really need the function `get_color`. You can just use `get_at` where it is needed.